# communicatio between xhtml page and backend bean

Tags: jsf-2

My question is if I have one xhtml page with components and one of them is on sample

```
<h:inputText id="input" value="#{userBean.name}" 
           valueChangeListener="#{userBean.valueChanged}"/>
```

and if I have appropriate method in backend bean:

```
    public valuseCHanged(ValueChangeEvent e){

        (UIInput)input=(UIInput)e.getSource;
UISelectOne listbox = (UISelectOne)input.findComponent("listbox");
    ......
        }
```

What is send to the back-and bean, some Object e of ValueChanged class. Bath its objects properties in relation to the this component where was made changes or on sample for all page? And what input value represents, after that?And why we have line input.findComponent("ID_of_anoder_component") on sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is send to the back-and bean,

username.name is mapped to name field of userbean provided setter method is provided and the method `valueChanged` gets called whenever the value of `name` is changed.

> And what input value represents

input value represents the value of the backing bean field called name. You have a class `UserBean` and a field `name`. so it will represent `name` value.

> And why we have line input.findComponent("ID_of_anoder_component") on
>   sample?

This method gets called when the value of `name` changes and whenever that happens, the methods finds out the compoent `listbox`

Comment: for value=""  is ok, bath what valueChangeListener is main the questinons. What represent (ValueChangeEvent e) in calls it is object who related on whole page or on determined component?

Comment: `valueChangeListener="#{userBean.valueChanged}"` ValueChangeEvent will be applicable for any component that is using valueChangeListener method. It can be acorss whole page depending on the placement of component and binding

Comment: ok if we can to back on e.getSource this return
The object on which the Event initially occurred.
The questions is what this object represent xhtml page, form on this page or only component where we have valueChangeListener attribute?

Comment: @vmaric, yes it will return the source of the event

Comment: it represents the object that has caused this event to trigger.

Comment: :) Bath logically if we look on the xhtml page there is head,  body form and menu components, where on sample one of them have valueChangeListener. And when generated this object which information it have according to the page. About all page only form or only components in form or only about component who make event?

Comment: components who make event.